# Vertex Array tile map collision

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I am working with a small tile-map using 16x16 pixel tiles. The player moves in 1 pixel spaces, meaning that there are certain points in which the player is in more than one tile. My current method finds a single tile, but it is fairly inaccurate and you cannot go within 16px of the tile you should not be able to pass.

Collision function:

```
void collision(direction dir)
{
    m_Position = m_Sprite.getPosition();
    long x = m_Position.x;
    long y = m_Position.y;

    long current = ((x - (x % TextureSize)) / TextureSize) + (((((y - (y % TextureSize))) / TextureSize) * LevelWidth));


    switch (dir)
    {
    case up:
        if (activelevel[current - LevelWidth] != 0)
            this->move(down);
        break;
    case down:
        if (activelevel[current + LevelWidth] != 0)
            this->move(up);
        break;
    case left:
        if (activelevel[current + 1 ] != 0)
            this->move(right);
        break;
    case right:
        if (activelevel[current - 1] != 0)
            this->move(left);
        break;
    }

}
```

Movement function:

```
void move(direction dir)
{


    switch (dir)
    {
    case up:
        m_Sprite.move(0,-1 * speed);
        break;
    case right:
        m_Sprite.move(1 * speed, 0);
        break;
    case down:
        m_Sprite.move(0, 1 * speed);
        break;  
    case left:
        m_Sprite.move(-1 * speed, 0);
        break;  
    default:
        break;  
    }


    if (animated == true && dir != not)
        animate(dir);

    collision(dir);

}
```

Has anyone got any ideas of a method to do this? They would not need to be related to above.

Thanks.

Comment: And the question is??

Comment: @DGomez Edited, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: You only need to test if your move would place you *outside* of the current rectangle. That said: 1. isn't your 'own' size important? Or are you moving a single pixel around? 2. probably better to change `collision` to return if it is possible to move in that direction, and test it before actually moving.

Comment: 16*16 Sprite, sorry I omitted that. My problem is more that if the player is in two squares. Would that mean that I need to test both the squares in front?